# Laravel/LaraCSV - Global Variable in beforeEach

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function in my Controller where I'm trying to export a .csv file using LaraCSV. This is their available documentation: https://github.com/usmanhalalit/laracsv#full-documentation. For whatever reason, I can't seem to use the `$doctor` variable that I declared earlier in the function into the `beforeEach` function for LaraCSV. Is anyone aware of how this can be accomplished? Or will I need to perform another `where()` find from the patient to the doctor?

```
public function doctorCSV($id) {
    $csvExporter = new \Laracsv\Export();
    $doctor = Doctor::findOrFail($id);
    $scripts = $doctor->scripts()->get();

    $csvExporter->beforeEach(function ($script) {
        $patients = Patient::all();
        $patient = $patients->where('id', $script->patient_id)->first();
        $script->patient = $patient->full_name;
        $script->doctor = $doctor->full_name;
    });

    return $csvExporter
        ->build($scripts, [
            'prescribe_date' => 'Prescribe Date',
            'doctor' => 'Doctor',
            'patient' => 'Patient',
            'status' => 'Status'
        ])
        ->download('Report - ' . $doctor->full_name . ' - ' . date('m-d-Y') . '.csv');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php `Closure` statement like this

```
$csvExporter->beforeEach(function ($script) use($doctor) { // here
        $patients = Patient::all();
        $patient = $patients->where('id', $script->patient_id)->first();
        $script->patient = $patient->full_name;
        $script->doctor = $doctor->full_name;
    });
```